# How to change the default GPU devise in TensorFlow 2.1

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I've been trying to get my TensorFlow to use the GeForce graphics card for a while and couldn't work out why it hasn't been utilising it.

I can now see that TensorFlow is using a different GPU as the default.

I wondered how I change the default GPU.

[Script further showing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st82r.png)

Comment: I don't see what evidence you have that it is using "a different GPU", it seels to be using your RTX 2080

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro when I look at the task manager whilst running a script there is no activity on the GPU. Also, TensorFlow says that the default GPU device is "/device:GPU:0" Which is not the GeForce RTX 2080

Comment: Which physical device is /device:GPU:0 then? What other GPUs do you have in the system? Low utilization/activity can mean other issues (like small models).